# How to prove two statements are equivalent and give a counterexample if they're not.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I'm trying to solve this question.

Let A be a set and P(x) and Q(x) be statements with one variable
Are the statements

> $$((∃x ∈ A)(P(x)))∨((∃x ∈ A)(Q(x)))$$
>   and$$(∃x ∈ A)(P(x)∨Q(x))$$

equivalent? If yes give a proof. Give a counterexample if false. But I'm currently stuck in how to prove they are equivalent, I don't know where to start. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you put the statements into words? I think your intuition is likely to see whether the two statements are the same if you do - being able to do this translation is a significant portion of the problem.

Comment: **Hint:** The first expression asserts that there exists an $\ x\ $ in $\ A\ $ such that either $\ P(x)\ $ or $\  Q(x)\ $ is true.  The second asserts that either there exists an $\ x\ $ in $\ A\ $ such that $\ P(x)\ $ is true or there exists an $\ x\ $ in $\ A\ $ such that $\ Q(x)\ $ is true.

Comment: I've reached that point, I believe they are equivalent but I'm struggling to prove it. Thanks for the hint tho.

Comment: I think I got the hang of it after looking through my notes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove equivalence, you have show that statement 1 implies statement 2, and statement 2 implies statement 1. To begin, start with the assumption that $((\exists x \in A)(P(x)))\lor ((\exists x \in A)(Q(x)))$ and show that this implies $(\exists x \in A)(P(x)\lor Q(x))$. After, you assume the second and show that it implies the first.

An example of the start of the proof would be along the lines "Assume $((\exists x \in A)(P(x)))\lor ((\exists x \in A)(Q(x)))$, then..."

Comment: Thanks, I got the hang of it!